# Flyway with multi million rows

Tags: postgresql, import, flyway

I need to insert 3-4 million rows into a PostgreSQL database. This will be static lookup data.

We have various staging environments on the way to production. I have seen all the answers here on Stack Overflow about how we could do it not using Flyway, but has anybody got any experience with using Flyway when dealing with this quantity of data? Is it a non-starter?  Flyway perfectly solves all of the problems we are facing.

Internet searching doesn't really turn up much for this so I am guessing that Flyway just isn't meant for dealing with this quantity of data but I would be interested if anybody has tried it and what they found out. If this is even remotely possible, how should we divide the import files size-wise for optimisation?

Comment: Do you need to support other databases than PostgreSQL with that?

Comment: nope just PostgreSQL

Comment: You could have a CSV file and load it with `COPY`.

Comment: I am happy to write lots of import sql statements if that is viable, just wondering if anybody has imported that amount of data with flyway in the wild!

Comment: Looking into this with our development team. I'll see what kind of answer I can get for you.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? It might be easier as a Java migration than a SQL one - https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#java-based-migrations - where the Java code reads from the external source, constructs the appropriate INSERT and executes it (using the jdbcTemplate field) rather than you constructing a huge collection of SQL INSERT statements.

Comment: @julia Hayward the issue is making the data source for the static data visible to every environment, security team wouldn't be happy with the production environment using  the same data source as development so we then have to create a dedicated data source per environment and then populate that somehow and it gets a bit messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it ended up being around 3 million records. We broke the files into 100,000 records per file so about 30 files. Flyway has no issue at all with this, it takes 30 seconds or so to run the scripts.

We're not sure we are going to use flyway to keep the records up to date, but for priming the data it has been the perfect solution